# How to make lm interpret eval in formula

Tags: r

I was hoping to get lm() to accept a character string as formula input but it does not quite work. This works so far:

```
 Test<-as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:100, 12), 4, 3))
 colnames(Test)<-c("Y", "X1", "X2")
 lm(Y~X1, data=Test)
 XT1<-"X1"
 lm(Y~eval(parse(text=XT1)), data=Test)
```

This works fine and produces the correct output. However, when I trie to have more than one parameter:

```
 lm(Y~X1+X2, data=Test)
 XT2<-"X1+X2"
 lm(Y~eval(parse(text=XT2)), data=Test)
```

This does not produce the same result. I wonder why since obviously the character strings are both interpreted correctly:

```
 parse(text=XT1)
 parse(text=XT2)
```

For the background: In the end this should work in a function, where a matrix of parameters is supplied and the XT2 string should be dynamically created from the colnames of the matrix, so I'd need a solution that works with XT2 of all possible lengths between 1 and (hypothetically) infinity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `eval(parse())` until you are an advanced R user (and then you usually won't need it). Just use `as.formula`:

```
lm(as.formula(paste0("Y ~ ", XT2)), data=Test)
```

Note that a better strategy for your goal would be:

```
lm(Y ~ ., data=Test[, c("Y", "X1", "X2")])
```

Answer (score 2):

with eval(parse(x)) you execute the string x as code, so in this case you first add X1 and X2 creating 1 variable and then run the regression.